# Change text color to red for all the labels and show red border for all invalid fields after submitting form angularjs

Tags: forms, angularjs, css, validation

I have a form, which has a couple of text areas and bootstrap UI star ratings with their label texts.  I have set all the text areas and star ratings as required fields.

I would like to change all the label texts (i.e. ) for the text areas ()/the star ratings () to red font and have red border around the text areas for all invalid fields when I click on the submit button.  Below are my code, which is Not working.

I would like the following to happen when I click on the save button without typing anything.  Can you please tell me how I can achieve these 3 items?

1. Change border around the invalid text areas to be red
2. Change the font color for the labels of the invalid text areas to red
3. Change the front color for the labels of the invalid star (if user didn't select at least 1 star rating) ratings to turn red.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Here is the html:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12">
                <form name="addReviewForm" class="addReview-form" role="addReviewForm" ng-class="{submitted:addReviewForm.submitted}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="reviewTitle">Review Title:</label>
                        <br />
                        <textarea ng-model="review.title" id="reviewTitle" class="form-control" name="reviewTitle" rows="3" placeholder="Write your review title here" required></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Review:</label>
                        <textarea ng-model="review.comments" class="form-control" name="comments" rows="3" placeholder="Write your review here" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12">
                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <dt>On time deliver:</dt>
                    <dd>
                        <rating value="review.Time" max="max" readonly="false" rating-states="ratingStates" name="onTime" required></rating>
                    </dd>
                    <dt>Customer service:</dt>
                    <dd>
                        <rating value="review.CustomerService" max="max" readonly="false" rating-states="ratingStates" name="customerService" required></rating>
                    </dd>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the function that is being invoked when the 'save' button is clicked:

```
$scope.addReview = function (review) {
    if ($scope.addReviewForm.$valid) {
        //submit as normal

    }
    else {
        $scope.addReviewForm.submitted = true;
    }
}
```

Here is my css:

```
addReviewForm.submitted .ng-dirty.ng-invalid{ 
    border: 1px solid red; 
} 
addReviewForm.submitted .ng-dirty.ng-valid{
     border: 1px solid green; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Brocco/NW8Y5/) with the following working as you described

Submit button: (this will set submitted to true)

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit Button</button>
```

HTML: (use ng-class to determine if the field is dirty and valid)

```
<div ng-app class="row" ng-init="review = {title: 'abc'}">
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12">
        <form name="addReviewForm" class="addReview-form" role="addReviewForm" ng-class="{submitted:submitted}">
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'show-valid': (addReviewForm.reviewTitle.$valid && addReviewForm.reviewTitle.$dirty), 'show-invalid': (addReviewForm.reviewTitle.$invalid && addReviewForm.reviewTitle.$dirty)}">
                <label for="reviewTitle">Review Title:</label>
                <br />
                <textarea ng-model="review.title" id="reviewTitle" class="form-control" name="reviewTitle" rows="3" placeholder="Write your review title here" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit Button</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS: (control the style of what is displayed)

```
.submitted .show-invalid textarea, .submitted .show-invalid input, .submitted .show-invalid select {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.submitted .show-valid textarea, .submitted .show-valid input, .submitted .show-valid select {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: thanks Brocco, but your example didn't change the text color for the label of the text area to red.  I found an example from http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/ANxmv/2/, which does that, but I couldn't get mine to work.  I revised th3 4th line of code in the html above to the code below, but it still didn't work.  Am I missing something?
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted]">

Comment: I applied the CSS classes at the .form-group level so you can appropriately style any element inside, so if you wanted to do the label you could do this: .submitted .show-invalid label { color: red; }

Comment: I added submitted .show-invalid label { color: red; }, but the label's font didn't turn red.  I am thinking this is because the label isn't "invalid".  If this is true, how can I turn the label's font for the text area to red when the text area is is invalid?  Plus, In my original question, I also need to change the cont color of the <rating> (star rating) to red.  I added 'required in the <rating>, but if i didn't select a star/rating, it didn't turn the rating to invalid.  How can i make the rating to be required and set the label for the star rating to have red font color?  thanks!

Comment: @user3439326 : Where you able to change the font color of label when input element is invalid?